# make oldconfig error 1

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, fedora

I built my kernel using fedpkg local (which took 6 hours and I hope I don't have to repeat the process)
Now when I try to use the command "make oldconfig" it returns with the following error

```
Makefile: 10: recipe for target 'oldconfig' failed
make: *** [oldconfig] Error 1
```

Can somebody tell me what this means and how to resolve it?

Comment: The whole error log (or at least preceding errors) will be helpful. Also reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of stackoverflow is a good when you start asking (to understand how to ask and what to do with the answers here).

Comment: Where can I locate my log files? That's the entire error message, there's nothing before it

Comment: There has to be something before it.  This message is just telling you that the recipe make tried to invoke for the `oldconfig` target didn't work.  It's up to the recipe itself to generate some useful error message.  What is output between the command you typed and the above text?

Comment: I was in the wrong directory! My make file was in a different directory other than my current one.